# How to retrieve data from vault android app

Tags: security

I am using vault android app for hiding my secret data. Unfortunately i have moved every things in Internal memory to External SD card. Now I am able to see my secret documents,photos and videos while opening the vault application. I am able to locate the folder SystemAndroid but i don't know what to do for retrieve my data.please help

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! This happens to be a question frequently asked on our site. Have you tried our on-site search? See [How do I search?](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/searching) for help using it. Quick starters: [retrieve vault](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=retrieve+vault) / [restore vault](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=restore+vault). Please check if any of those (5+8 links altogether) solve your issue, then let us know the outcome. Thanks, and good luck!

Answer (score -1):

go to Systemandroid  then MXGKJHzyoi== like folder then .image contains photos and .video contains videos. Hexedit any file from .image folder and find data starting from FFD8 AND FFD9 IS end . and save as jpeg. you can see all images.

Comment: Can you format this better? It's hard to follow what you're saying.